# How to compare two tables, in order to calculate the growth rate between two time periods?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, window-functions

The table I currently have looks like this:
(data comes from two different tables, 19921231, 19930331)

[image]

The table I want to create looks like this (5th column added)

[image]

Goal: determine the deposit growth rate at each bank.  I.e. Comparing the amount of deposits held at a bank in the previous quarter (e.g. 19921231) to the deposits of the most recent quarter (e.g. 19930331). Then view the increase/decrease as a percentage.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
select 
AL.repdte as `Date`, AL.cert, AL.name, AL.dep as `Deposits`
FROM usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as AL

UNION ALL

select 
AL.repdte as `Date`, AL.cert, AL.name, AL.dep as `Deposits`
FROM usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as AL
```

An answer to this question suggested this code, that works
However, for some reason I getting an output of "NULL"

```
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and
        al19930331.name = al19921231.name and
        al19921231.repdte = date_add(al19930331.repdte, interval 1 year);
```

[image]

In an attempt to isolate the "NULL" issue, I reduced the query to it's simplest terms, and was able to eliminate the "NULL" issue.

[image]

Now we have deposit columns for both quarters returning what appears to be proper outputs.

Next I removed the last line of code from:

```
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and
        al19930331.name = al19921231.name and
        al19921231.repdte = date_add(al19930331.repdte, interval 1 year);
```

Removing the last line of code worked, sort of. Running the code produces a "division by zero" error. How can one eliminate the division by zero error?

```
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and
        al19930331.name = al19921231.name
```

Comment: What is your database?  If MySQL, are you using version 8 or later?

Comment: Using BigQuery Standard SQL

Comment: There was a real `LAG` in your reply, but see the helpful answer below by @GMB which looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be storing this information in different tables.  This should all be in the same table using different *partitions*.  But with the date embedded in the middle of the name, I think you need to use an explicit `join`:

```
    select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993_0331,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992_1231,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and 
     al19921231.repdte = date_add(al19930331.repdte, interval 1 quarter);
```

This would be simpler with the data in one table.

Comment: Receiving NULL on Deposits_1992, and Growth_rate. select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993_0331,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992_1231,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and 
     al19921231.repdte = date_add(al19930331.repdte, interval 1 quarter);

Comment: @user2755660 . . . Then you don't have matching values in the previous year.  Perhaps the names don't match.

Comment: Paired the query down in order to eliminate the Null.  Now am returning deposit values for both quarters. Now just need to reason. Wondering if it could be a division/zero issue. 
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993_0331,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992_1231,
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    100.0 
        * (deposits - lag(deposits) over(partition by cert order by depdte)) 
        / lag(deposits) over(partition by cert order by depdte) as growth_percent
from mytable t
```